# Ezra 10:3 "put away" or "yatsa' " Why not "garash"?

Tags: ezra-nechemya

What are the differences and what does it imply?

Comment: If gerushin relates to halachic divorce and these women are not Jewish (so there was, therefore, no halachic marriage) then the language of divorce would not apply.